# Outlook crashes when reading mail

Tags: outlook, gdi+, hardware-acceleration

We have an outlook addin installed, and while opening some of the html-emails, outlook crashes. If we remove the addin, the emails open properly without outlook getting crashed.
The addin isn't supposed to do anything while opening emails. We can't figure out why outlook is crashing beacause of our addin.
We have also disabled hardware acceleration rendering
We analysed the crashdump and what we got in debuglog is pasted below:

```
FAULTING_IP: 
GdiPlus!ScanOperation::Blend_sRGB_sRGB_MMX+43
4ec5ed94 8907            mov     dword ptr [edi],eax

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
.exr 0xffffffffffffffff
ExceptionAddress: 4ec5ed94 (GdiPlus!ScanOperation::Blend_sRGB_sRGB_MMX+0x00000043)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000001
   Parameter[1]: a915a784
Attempt to write to address a915a784

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ

PROCESS_NAME:  OUTLOOK.EXE

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  a915a784

WRITE_ADDRESS:  a915a784 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
GdiPlus!ScanOperation::Blend_sRGB_sRGB_MMX+43
4ec5ed94 8907            mov     dword ptr [edi],eax

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
!dumpstack -EE
No export dumpstack found

FAULTING_THREAD:  00001508

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  INVALID_POINTER_READ

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ_INVALID_POINTER_WRITE

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 4ec5f3a3 to 4ec5ed94

STACK_TEXT:  
0013a61c 4ec5f3a3 0000000e 13965ec0 a915a784 GdiPlus!ScanOperation::Blend_sRGB_sRGB_MMX+0x43
0013a638 4ed2aaa2 a915a784 13965ec0 0000000e GdiPlus!EpAlphaBlender::Blend+0x57
0013a690 4ed2ac57 00002000 13965ea8 139663a8 GdiPlus!EpScanGdiDci::DrawScanRecords_Dci+0x1de
0013a6e0 4ecc9c24 00000001 13965ea8 139663a8 GdiPlus!EpScanGdiDci::ProcessBatch_Dci+0x182
0013a704 4ec66d7b 0013a7b8 0013a870 4ec5f2c0 GdiPlus!EpScanGdiDci::EmptyBatch+0xaa
0013a710 4ec5f2c0 0000000e 00000000 4ec619ab GdiPlus!EpScanGdiDci::End+0x1e
0013a71c 4ec619ab 130027f8 13002850 130028d0 GdiPlus!EpScanBufferNative<unsigned long>::~EpScanBufferNative<unsigned long>+0x18
0013a870 4ec9d872 13975eb8 0013a994 130033c8 GdiPlus!DpDriver::DrawImage+0x1ba
0013a8e4 4ec61459 13956260 0013a994 13003548 GdiPlus!DriverMulti::DrawImage+0x78
0013ad40 4ec60d39 0013adb8 13965310 00000003 GdiPlus!GpGraphics::DrvDrawImage+0x2351
0013adf4 4ec609d7 00000000 130021a4 00000000 GdiPlus!GpGraphics::DrawImage+0x215
0013ae60 3d00769f 13956208 13965310 43470000 GdiPlus!GdipDrawImageRectRect+0x1b3
0013aea0 3d0075f3 00000000 00000000 41600000 mshtml!Gdiplus::Graphics::DrawImage+0x62
0013af20 3d123052 0013b0a8 00000000 00e8236d mshtml!XHDC::DrawImage+0x503
0013af80 3d2288bb 0013b0a8 0013b004 0013afe4 mshtml!CImgBitsDIB::StretchBlt+0x2ca
0013b028 3d1607e3 00000640 0013b0a8 1db7d978 mshtml!DrawPlaceHolder+0x33e
0013b0b8 3cf6d4ed 1d99ffd8 0013f658 0013f658 mshtml!CImgHelper::Draw+0x23f
0013b0d0 3cf9b516 0013f658 133f00d0 1d88da2c mshtml!CImgElementLayout::Draw+0x1a
0013b10c 3cf9b461 0013b1a0 0013b164 137215c0 mshtml!CLayout::DrawClient+0x62
0013b4c4 3cf98edf 137e1f88 00000000 00000007 mshtml!CDispLeafNode::DrawSelf+0x432
0013b610 3cf995fe 00000000 137e1f88 00000000 mshtml!CDispNode::Draw+0x217
0013b638 3cf9958e 137e1f88 0013b808 00000000 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawChildren+0x56
0013b7fc 3cf98edf 137e1f88 1d98a220 00000007 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawSelf+0x28a
0013b948 3cf995fe 00000000 137e1f88 00000000 mshtml!CDispNode::Draw+0x217
0013b970 3cf9958e 137e1f88 0013bb40 00000000 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawChildren+0x56
0013bb34 3cf98edf 137e1f88 1d8fb008 00000007 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawSelf+0x28a
0013bc80 3cf995fe 00000000 137e1f88 00000000 mshtml!CDispNode::Draw+0x217
0013bca8 3cf9958e 137e1f88 0013be78 00000000 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawChildren+0x56
0013be6c 3cf98edf 137e1f88 1d8fafd0 00000007 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawSelf+0x28a
0013bfb8 3cf995fe 00000000 137e1f88 00000000 mshtml!CDispNode::Draw+0x217
0013bfe0 3cf9958e 137e1f88 0013c1b0 00000000 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawChildren+0x56
0013c1a4 3cf98edf 137e1f88 1d8fed68 00000007 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawSelf+0x28a
0013c2f0 3cf995fe 00000000 137e1f88 00000000 mshtml!CDispNode::Draw+0x217
0013c318 3cf9958e 137e1f88 0013c4e8 00000000 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawChildren+0x56
0013c4dc 3cf98edf 137e1f88 1db6fc7c 00000007 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawSelf+0x28a
0013c628 3cf995fe 00000000 137e1f88 00000000 mshtml!CDispNode::Draw+0x217
0013c650 3cf9958e 137e1f88 0013c820 00000000 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawChildren+0x56
0013c814 3cf98edf 137e1f88 1d889588 00000007 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawSelf+0x28a
0013c960 3cf995fe 00000000 137e1f88 00000000 mshtml!CDispNode::Draw+0x217
0013c988 3cf9958e 137e1f88 0013cb58 00000000 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawChildren+0x56
0013cb4c 3cf98edf 137e1f88 137ea79c 00000007 mshtml!CDispContainer::DrawSelf+0x28a
0013cc98 3cf9c490 00000000 137e1f88 00000000 mshtml!CDispNode::Draw+0x217
0013cd48 3ceb0ed7 1d831158 137e1f88 00000000 mshtml!CDispRoot::DrawEntire+0x88
0013f53c 3cf98d12 137215c0 137e1f88 0013f658 mshtml!CDispRoot::DrawRoot+0x319
0013f5ec 3cf9807e 137c3ec8 0013f658 ba0415b1 mshtml!CView::RenderView+0x3b6
0013faa0 3cf7ed29 0000000f 00000000 137c3cd8 mshtml!CDoc::OnPaint+0x5c7
0013fad4 3cfa9457 137c3cd8 0000000f 00000000 mshtml!CServer::OnWindowMessage+0x38f
0013fbfc 3cfa9331 137c3cd8 0000000f 00000000 mshtml!CDoc::OnWindowMessage+0x16c
0013fc28 7e418734 001304b8 0000000f 00000000 mshtml!CServer::WndProc+0x78
0013fc54 7e418816 3cfa92e5 001304b8 0000000f user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
0013fcbc 7e42a013 00000000 3cfa92e5 001304b8 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x150
0013fcec 7e42a039 ffff0673 001304b8 0000000f user32!CallWindowProcAorW+0x98
0013fd0c 3026f4d5 ffff0673 001304b8 0000000f user32!CallWindowProcW+0x1b
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0013fd34 7e418734 001304b8 0000000f 00000000 OUTLLIB!FAllowStoreToSend+0x264ff
0013fd60 7e418816 3026f476 001304b8 0000000f user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x28
0013fdc8 7e428ea0 00000000 3026f476 001304b8 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x150
0013fe1c 7e428eec 006697a8 0000000f 00000000 user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xa3
0013fe44 7c90e473 0013fe54 00000018 006697a8 user32!__fnDWORD+0x24
0013fe68 7e4194d2 7e428f10 0013fee4 00000000 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x13
0013feb0 7e418a10 0013fee4 00000000 0013ff04 user32!NtUserDispatchMessage+0xc
0013fec0 30d157fe 0013fee4 0013fee4 300592a7 user32!DispatchMessageW+0xf
0013ff04 3000139e 00000000 00000000 00000000 MSO!Ordinal326+0x21
0013ffc0 7c817077 00380039 00350039 7ffdf000 OUTLOOK+0x139e
0013fff0 00000000 30001084 00000000 00000000 kernel32!BaseProcessStart+0x23


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  GdiPlus!ScanOperation::Blend_sRGB_sRGB_MMX+43

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: GdiPlus

IMAGE_NAME:  GdiPlus.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a841b37

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_GdiPlus.dll!ScanOperation::Blend_sRGB_sRGB_MMX

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ_INVALID_POINTER_WRITE_GdiPlus!ScanOperation::Blend_sRGB_sRGB_MMX+43

Followup: MachineOwner
```

I appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: @user537788 is this a plugin you are writing? or are you just using a third party plugin?